# Data (char*) appears corrupt when logged after pressing button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pointers

I'm quite newbie to iphone programming. 
The problem is when I push a button, a data will be destroyed.
I can't find where my code is wrong and why. Please help me.

This is overview of my program.

```
1. load text data from "sample.txt"
2. log the data
3. When I push a button, it logs the data again.
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *myButton1;
@property (assign) unsigned char* bytePtr;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
~snip~

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [self.myButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 ,100)];
    [self.myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1DidPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.myButton1 setTitle:@"push" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.window addSubview:self.myButton1];
    [self load];

    return YES;
}


- (void) load
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
    NSLog(@"%s", self.bytePtr);
}


- (void)button1DidPushed
{
    UIAlertView *alerView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter something..." message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    alerView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alerView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {

    }
    NSLog(@"%s", self.bytePtr);
}

~snip~
```

sample.txt:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
<----- When I push the button the mark similar to "?" will appear on output window.(I couldn't show it here(It's probabily ascii code 2(STX))) That is why I think the data is destroyed.
```

Environment:

```
xcode 6.0.1
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're expecting your `bytePtr` to store the data, it won't.  The value of that pointer will be meaningless as soon as `data` goes out of scope.  You should have a read about pointers / general C programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not retaining the `NSData` object:

```
- (void) load
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];   // here
    self.bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
    NSLog(@"%s", self.bytePtr);
}
```

Once that method returns the `NSData` object will be destroyed and therefore the buffer pointed to by `self.bytePtr` is no longer valid.

To solve this issue change `self.bytePtr` to an `NSData` object and store that instead.

Comment: @keimina Forgot to mention, if that data is made up of characters you should be using an `NSString` instead of `NSData`.  So convert the `NSData` to an `NSString`, with the required encoding, and store that instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to receive your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method call, you need to set your UIAlertView delegate to self.

```
[alertView setDelegate:self] // make sure you set UIAlertViewDelegate protocol on the method owner
```

Otherwise you should use an `NSString` object initialized using `initWithData:encoding:`.